# Android - JSON to textview using asynctask

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm creating a Movie Catalog app. I have a problem, I want to get `detailmovie` (from the movie id). I send the id movie from the `listview` I get, I already created the `DetailActivity` and I test get the movie title but it doesn't work. What can i do?

here's my code

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txt_title,txt_detail,txt_rate;
ImageView img_posterd;

public static String API_KEY = "f00e74c69ff0512cf9e5bf128569f****";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String idmov = i.getStringExtra("idmovie");

    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+idmov+"?api_key="+API_KEY+"&language=en-US";
    txt_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title_detail);
    new GetMovieTask(txt_title).execute(url);

}

private class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    TextView txt_title;

    public GetMovieTask(TextView txt_title) {
        this.txt_title = txt_title;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String title = "UNDEFINED";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            title = object.getString("original_title");

            urlConnection.disconnect();
            Log.d("titlenya", title);

        }catch (IOException | JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return title;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String original_title) {
        txt_title.setText("Ti : " +original_title);
    }
}

}
```

I'm using `themoviedb` API.
loopj library for the listview.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Also, you don't ever want to show your API key.

Comment: my Log.d not showed,,and textview is not changed

Comment: Are you getting an error in logcat?

Comment: no,i didnt get an error,,but my code doesnt work

Comment: I suggest you put your app in debug mode and step through execution to determine where it is failing.

Comment: 08-26 23:26:27.871 20145-20862/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for original_title

,,i got the error finally

Comment: The catch is executing. That's why you don't see your log message.

Comment: thks sir,already worked :)

Comment: Great! Remember to keep your api key secret. If what you posted is your real key, you will want to change it.

Comment: okayy sir,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not take JSON like that. And hence your code throws this

```
08-26 23:26:27.871 20145-20862/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for original_title
```

first you have to read response from the webservice in the form of string and then use `JSONObject = new JSONObject(string);` to convert it to a JSONObject. For example

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    Log.i(TAG, "POST Response Code: " + responseCode);

    //Takes data only if response from WebService is OK
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        //Stores input line by line in response
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //get data in JSON
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        title = object.getString("original_title");

        urlConnection.disconnect();
        Log.d("titlenya", title);

    }
} catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```